# JSON object properties are undefined in Maps event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

I've read a few threads here and I understand there's a scope issue with my `globalSettings` properties not being available in the `google.maps.event.addDomListener` function.

The `console.log` statement returns `undefined`, but if I do `console.log(globalSettings)`, it shows the object and its properties.

How do I make the properties available so I can use them to initialize the map center and zoom?

```
var globalSettings = jQuery.parseJSON(wpmm_settings);
var ICON = new google.maps.MarkerImage('medicare.png', null, null,
    new google.maps.Point(14, 13));

var SHADOW = new google.maps.MarkerImage('medicare-shadow.png', null, null,
    new google.maps.Point(14, 13));

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(globalSettings) {
    console.log(globalSettings.map_center_lat);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(globalSettings.map_center_lat, 135),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });...
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this has much to do with Google Maps API. It appears to concern the behaviour of JSON objects in event handling. It would help if you could say exactly what `wpmm_settings` was and exactly what `globalSettings` contained.

Comment: thanks Andrew, you can see it on this page: http://demo.wpconsult.net/sample/sub-page-11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wpmm_settings` is a string:

```
"[{\"default_zoom\":\"8\",\"map_center_lat\":\"51.4992913\",\"map_center_lng\":\"-0.1639785\"}]"
```

`globalSettings` is the result of parsing that string:

```
[Object { default_zoom="8", map_center_lat="51.4992913", map_center_lng="-0.1639785"}]
```

Note that it ends up as a single-element array, because of the outermost square brackets.

The value of `map_center_lat` is accessed as `globalSettings[0].map_center_lat`.

If you took the outermost square brackets out of the string, you would get a single "naked" object, and the properties can be accessed as you expect.

#### Then...

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(globalSettings) {...`

does not pass `globalSettings` to the event handler. The *event* is passed — this is the standard behaviour: the event is passed to the event handler. What this line does is set `globalSettings` inside that function to the `window.load` event. So you need to replace that mention of `globalSettings` with something like `evt` which you can ignore inside the function.

There are still issues with your `...` of code in your snippet, but getting the object and the event handler right will make finding those easier.

Comment: wow, what a stupid mistake, thank you thank you!! really appreciate your help Andrew, you're the man